# Pre-existing network identity in scene crashing clients joining the host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a problem in my unity project where I try to host a network game on my host and the game crashes for the clients joining. I think it has something to do with the network identity in the scene. I connect to the server in a scene and then switch to the game scene. On the host it works fine, but then on the client my gameobject with a network identity is disabled and it bugs out.

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem. I put a offline scene and an online scene in my network manager gameobject. Then let the server change scenes itself.

Hope it helps.